# kodo/jdo/FatalInternalException?

Tags: java, exception, jndi

Does anyone have an idea why this error happens or where I can get the JAR file which contains this class?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kodo/jdo/FatalInternalException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:164)
        at $Proxy0.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:588)
        at weblogic.iiop.ProxyDesc.readResolve(ProxyDesc.java:45)
        ... 45 more
```

My application uses `wlclient.jar` to perform a `JNDI` lookup... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/search/~FatalInternalException~) for this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the jar named kodo* (i.e. something like -jdo-). This jar should be in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I have a jdo-* file in my classpath but it contains the wrong class:

```
javax/jdo/JDOFatalInternalException.class
```

The package starts with javax and not kodo and also the class name is prefixed with JDO...

Answer (score 0):

use weblogic.jar instead of wlcient.jar